# ¿Cuándo utilizar el Upcasting de Clases en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo entendido que el Downcasting se utiliza para convertir de un tipo superior a un tipo inferior en la jerarquía de clases, esto para poder acceder a los métodos de la subclase.

Mi duda es, ¿Cómo porque yo querría hacer Upcasting? Si se supone que yo puedo acceder a los métodos de la súper clase a través de la herencia.

Comment: Lo que quieres es acceder a los métodos de la clase padre desde la hija? Disculpa pero no acabo de entender tu pregunta

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Lo que estoy diciendo es lo que yo entiendo por el concepto de Downcasting y al mismo tiempo estoy preguntado que sentido tendría hacer Upcasting.

Answer (score 3):

El upcasting se usa cuando realmente te da igual cuál es la clase específica de la instancia con la que trabajas y quieres que tu código sea lo más genérico posible. Un ejemplo muy habitual es usar `List` en lugar de `ArrayList`, o incluso usar `Collection`:

```
List<MiClase> hagoAlgo(int n) {
    // es un ArrayList, pero realmente da igual
    List<MiClase> resultado = new ArrayList<>(); 
    // ...
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto es siempre y cuando los métodos de la clase padre sean públicos o protected donde se pueden sobreescribir, pero puede ocurrir que en la clase padre tengas métodos privados o final que, obviamente, no pueden ser accedidas por la clase hija y pues requieras usar dichos métodos para alguna razón.